# Can I use unnamed namespaces instead of static variables inside functions?

Tags: c++, static, unnamed-namespace

I have browsed all the relevant questions about unnamed namespaces, yet I cannot see if and how they can be used to replace a `static` variable in this context:

```
returnType dummyfun () {

    static int staticInt;

    // do something...
};
```

Comment: No. `static` inside a function and at global scope are very different things.

Comment: If you actually understand what `static` means on a variable inside a function then it should be obvious that it has absolutely no relation to unnamed namespaces.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely. Lecturing apart, the reason why it shouldn't be possible is obvious, but sometimes there are very non obvious ways to make things possible. That's why my question looks legitimate to me.

Answer (score 3):

An unnamed namespace cannot be used to replace an internal static variable.

Unnamed namespaces are declared outside of the scope of a function. They are useful to allow access to function and variable names within a translation unit while hiding those same names outside of the translation unit.

An internal static variable is a variable whose name is accessible only within the scope of the function where it is declared and whose extent persists between calls to the function.

Comment: You should elaborate that they are completely different things.